# JAXB implementing "equals" method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have 2 `.xsd` files and am using `cxf-xjc-plugin` to generate Java classes. However, I haven't found the solution for comparing (ie by invoking the `equals()` method) 2 classes with nested classes. I don't use another plugin.

How I should fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB generated classes do not have `equals` or `hashcode` implementations. In order to support generating that code, additional information would need to be added to the schemas. There are other libraries, like [JAXB2 Basics](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Home) which do support generating an `equals()` method.